# Звук, запись с микрофона и его обработка

Tags: c++, аудио, звукозапись

Дали задачу написать простой голосовой чат на c++. Какие есть средства для обработки звука, записи звука с микрофона, прослушивание звука. Если у вас есть какие-то классические примеры, то прикрепите пожалуйста. Далее я хочу создать клиент-серверное приложение, но со звуком ни разу не работал. Разработка будет под windows.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12574/Simple-audio-recording-program

Comment: WinAPI https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/waveform-audio-reference

Comment: Пример тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834184/%d0%90%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%88%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b0-c-%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba

Comment: Обработка - лишнее, наверно лучше спрашивать запись отдельно. Потому что обработка может быть простая (домножение на коэфициент меняет громкость звука),а могут быть многоэтажные математические формулы. С точки зрения названия эффектов это может быть от шумоподавления до дисторшна/фленджера ревербератор/эхо и т п.По реализации - это может быть как работа с wave-массивом, так и использования различных библиотек, например DirectX фильтров. Но думаю всётаки имеется ввиду получить массив с wave волной, который уже можно будет как воспроизвести так и обработать.Т.е записать для дальнейшей обработки.